# How to get the mean curve(a set of points) of a boundary(a set of points) in 3d?

Tags: python, math, cgal

Assuming that I have a boundary(a set of points) like this:

[image: img]

how can I get the mean curve(a set of points) of a boundary(a set of points) in 3d?

Answer (score 1):

Your tags include CGAL, so look at Surface_mesh_skeletonization
[image]

Comment: But what I want is that the curve is on the surface, not in the mesh.

Comment: So you need 2D skeleton/medial axis ?

Comment: Not, this boundary is in 3d space, I just need the middle curve of this 3d boundary

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26458017)

Comment: @Bruno try clicking the link: it's not actually a link.  I've removed the link formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular figure, I think you can try fitting 2-degree polynomial with the least square method.

For more general figures you can try fitting lowest n-degree polynomial with the lowest variance again with the least square method. This is because if you go with higher degree polynomials, it will ultimately go through all the points and variance will go to zero. That's why try fitting smoothest lowest n-degree polynomial that cuts the original curve only at two points(i.e. points for lowest and highest y value).

I'm suggesting this because I'm a physics student and I tried basically this on hysteresis curve with 3-degree polynomial and got the mean curve for it.

Comment: but it may be a closed boundary, like ring.

Comment: I think it will work even for a closed 3D surface. You'll just need to fit a 3D polynomial.
It's interesting though.
Do you have just points on this 3D surface?